# How many graphs are there such that every vertex has degree at most 3?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

Recently, I saw this question [How many graphs are there such that every vertex has degree at most 2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849265/how-many-graphs-are-there-such-that-every-vertex-has-degree-at-most-2) about finding the number of labeled and unlabeled graphs with vertices having degree at most two. Number of vertices is fixed to a given $n$.

My question is the following: Can this result be generalised to

- A) Determining the number of i) labeled, ii) unlabeled undirected graphs with $n$ vertices of degree at most 3
- B) Determining the number of i) labeled, ii) unlabeled undirected graphs with $n$ vertices of degree 2,3

Evaluating the generating function seems sufficient.

Apart from isolated points, I had some idea to determine A from B: For every vertex with degree 2 from B, we can add a line (which ends in some point), so the vertex is degree three. That way, we can construct all graphs with vertices including degree 1.

Comment: I don't see in your post what the question is, what its hypotheses are, or what the "result" is.

Comment: Do you mean the number of such graphs who also have at most k vertices?

Comment: To be more clear: For a given number of vertices, determine the number of such graphs. Gen. function is equaly ok.

Comment: If the vertices have degree at most three then you can just string an arbitrary number of vertices into a line where each vertex has degree at most two.

Comment: However, that way, you only get some special graphs with that property. Consider large honeycomb (just truncate it), this also have vertices with degree three. Honeycomb example shows the set is very large.

Comment: That's enough to show there are an infinite number of them which answers the question.

Comment: My question is wrongly stated then. I have made a correction based on the older question in the link. Of course there are infinite number of them.

Comment: For the labeled case, see https://oeis.org/A136282; cf. D. E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 4A, Section 7.1.4.